How to select the Average of a Sum column in the same result
I have a table of operations with dates and quantities.



dateTime
quantity




2024-01-01
1


2024-02-5
2



I want to sum the quantities for each month and then group by each month, which is working fine.
Then i also want to average the sums above (Average over all quantities in the current year) and display the final result in one table.



Month
SUM(quantity)
AVG(XXX)




01
1860
1648


02
1899
1648


03
1677
1648


04
2166
1648


05
1576
1648


06
1718
1648


07
2144
1648


08
872
1648


09
924
1648



SELECT MONTH(o1.dateTime), SUM(o1.quantity)
FROM operation o1
WHERE o1.dateTime between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(o1.dateTime)


AVG(SUM(o1.quantity)) OVER ()

Use any one of query:
SELECT 
    MONTH(o1.dateTime) AS MONTH, 
    -- COUNT(MONTH(o1.dateTime)) as COUNT,
    SUM(o1.quantity) AS SUM,
    ROUND(SUM(o1.quantity)/COUNT(MONTH(o1.dateTime)), 2) AS AVG
FROM operation o1
WHERE o1.dateTime between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(o1.dateTime)

OR
SELECT 
    MONTH(o1.dateTime) AS MONTH, 
    -- COUNT(MONTH(o1.dateTime)) as COUNT,
    SUM(o1.quantity) AS SUM,
    ROUND(AVG(o1.quantity), 2) AS AVG
FROM operation o1
WHERE o1.dateTime between '2024-01-01' and '2024-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(o1.dateTime)

db<>fiddle

Hi, i tried your queries, but both of them don't give me the result i want.
as average i get something like 1.84 and 1.85 and so on, but i want the average of 1648 like displayed in the table above in my question, can you give me the query for that?

Why it will not work ? Share sample code...
or  check my testing code: https://dbfiddle.uk/P5HwNXOU @John919
